# Flash ActionScript 2 Slider Issue

Tags: flash, slider, actionscript-2

I found a script to make a slider in AS2. The problem is that the script constantly checks to see what frame i am on and i need it to not to do that. I think what i need is a way for it to  check once and set the frame number then if i slide the slider to start the check during that time and when done sliding the slider to stop checking again. This slider is going to be used in a banner ad served through Pointroll.

The issue is that with the constant checking its going to interfere with the tracking in pointroll.  Anyone have any thoughts?

---

My actionscript:

```
knob._x = track._x + track._width/3.75;
knob._y = track._y;
totalFrame = 79;

//var ratio:Number = track._width / 50;

knob.onPress = function():Void {
//var vertical:Number = track._y + (track._height / 2);
startDrag(knob,0,track._x,track._y,track._width+track._x-this._width,track._y);
this.onEnterFrame=function(){
    fNum=Math.ceil((this._x-track._x)/(track._width-this._width)*  (this._totalframes));
    if(fNum <= 2) fNum = 3;
    this.gotoAndStop(fNum);
}
} 
knob.onRelease = function():Void {
this.stopDrag();
delete this.onMouseMove;
}
//knob.onReleaseOutside = knob.onRelease;


onEnterFrame=function(){
fNum=int((knob._x-track._x)/(track._width-knob._width)*(totalFrame))+2;
trace(fNum);
this.gotoAndStop(fNum);
 }

 /* function updateKnobOutput():Void {
  trace((knob._x - track._x) / ratio);
 }*/

stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onEnterFrame` function is going to fire every time a frame is passed by the playhead. If your frame rate is 30fps and the playhead is stopped on this frame, that means that the code in `onEnterFrame` is executing 30 times per second.

If you don't need/want the code to execute that much, take it out of `onEnterFrame`.

Without having more context it's tough to give you any more specific advice than that.

Comment: so i should remove onEnterFrame and give that function a name instead? I'll try that out.

Comment: hmm, removing the onEnterFrame breaks the slider....meaning if i remove the onEnterFrame, publish my swf, the script no longer knows where the middle frame is and sliding the slider doesn't do anything.  What I am trying to accomplish is a slider that moves from frame1 to from 80 OR some range of frames.  I was binding the movieclip "track" to the total number of frames in the clip. I am also binding the movieclip "knob" to the "track" so sliding left to right and right left moves you up and down the timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first problem what I see, is that you setting 'onEnterFrame' every 'onPress', but don't delete 'onEnterFrame' when user releases the button.

I think that best way will be setting mouse move handler when user moves(drag) knob, and perform needed action inside that 'onMouseMove' handler, and delete(disable) 'onMouseMove' handler after user releases button.